# Errors in chi-squared test

Tags: r

I'm trying to test spatial data on COVID-19 positives in different regions of Japan.

Most of the code (Introduction) is working, but some parts (Problem area) are giving me errors, and I have no idea why.

I'd appreciate if someone could help me with a solution. Thank you in advance.

The data used is at the following link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LFoxxadqzYuemiss2EIm44I7SPJ5GGvz/view?usp=sharing

#### Introduction

```
library(spdep)
library(sf)
library(spatstat)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(DCluster)
library(splancs)
library(ggplot2)
needs::prioritize(magrittr)

covid19j <- readr::read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kaz-ogiwara/covid19/master/data/prefectures.csv")
covid19j_20200613 <- dplyr::filter(covid19j,
                                   year==2020,
                                   month==6,
                                   date==13)
covid19j_20200613$CODE <- 1:47
covid19j_20200613[is.na(covid19j_20200613)] <- 0
covid19j_20200613$serious <- as.numeric(covid19j_20200613$serious)
pop19 <- readr::read_csv("/cloud/project/covid19_data/covid19_data/pop2019.csv", locale=locale(encoding="UTF8"))
covid19j_20200613 <- dplyr::inner_join(covid19j_20200613, pop19, 
                                       by = c("CODE" = "CODE"))

jpn_pref <- sf::st_read("/cloud/project/covid19_data/covid19_data/jpn_pref.shp")
jpn_pref_cov19 <- dplyr::inner_join(jpn_pref, covid19j_20200613, by=c("PREF_CODE"="CODE" ))

covid19j_20200613$deaths <- as.numeric(covid19j_20200613$deaths)
covid19j_20200613$POP2019 <- as.numeric(covid19j_20200613$POP2019)
covid19j_20200613$deaths_rate <- covid19j_20200613$deaths / covid19j_20200613$POP2019 * 100
covid19j_20200613$testPos_rate <- covid19j_20200613$testedPositive / covid19j_20200613$peopleTested

jpn_pref <- sf::st_read('/cloud/project/covid19_data/covid19_data/jpn_pref.shp')
jpn_pref_cov19 <- dplyr::inner_join(jpn_pref, covid19j_20200613, 
                                    by=c("PREF_CODE"="CODE"))

pref_pnt <- sf::st_read('/cloud/project/covid19_data/covid19_data/pref_gov.shp')
pref_coord <-  data.frame(sf::st_coordinates(st_centroid(pref_pnt)))
pref.tri.nb <- sf::st_coordinates(st_centroid(pref_pnt)) %>%
  spdep::tri2nb()

covid19_OE <- data.frame(Observed=covid19j_20200613$deaths)
covid19_OE <- cbind(covid19_OE,
                     Expected=pop19$POP2019*sum(covid19j_20200613$deaths)/sum(pop19$POP2019),
                     x=pref_coord$X, y=pref_coord$Y
                     )
```

#### Problem area

```
achisq.stat(covid19_OE, lambda=1)
# Error in if (sum(data$Observed) == sum(data$Expected)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed


achisq.test(Observed~offset(log(Expected)), covid19_OE, model="poisson", R=100)
# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Observed", value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 47


covid19_achb_pb <- boot(covid19_OE, statistic=achisq.pboot, 
                        sim="parametric", ran.gen=poisson.sim, R=100)
# Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
```

MacBook Pro 2018，macOS Monterey，RStudio Cloud

Comment: The introduction is irrelevant.  To help you, we need to see the contents of the `covid19_0E` data frame.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  The words *minimal* and *reproducible* are both critical.

Comment: Your code fails for me on this line: `covid19j_20200613[is.na(covid19j_20200613)] <- 0` "Assigned data `0` must be compatible with existing data"